# Many to many relationship in microservices

Tags: c#, microservices

I have 2 microservices. We'll call them **IdentityDB** and **DB2**.

The first database "IdentityDB" has a identity `ASPNetUser`

The second database "DB2" has a Table `Competence`

The problem it a `ASPNetUser` has Many competences and `competence` has a Many ASPNetUsers.

I'm not sure how to properly handle this within a microservices architecture.

i try to create `profile` table in "**DB2**" has **`foreign keys`** form "**IdentityDB**" **ASPNetUser** and link `profile` with `competence` but im not sur it a good idea.

how to resolve it ?
to create a separate DB per service its best practices ?

Comment: Your microservices should be centered around business functions not entity relationships. We have to get more context.

Comment: You may have got the Microservices theory wrong. You don't design Database per microservice. Database will continue to be enterprise level design. Localizing/Normalizing as per standard practices. You break business data requests types into microservices and if there is a genuine reason to have individual database for that service - you can write a Feeder/Loader to batch load only the necessary data during Start/End of Day.

Comment: Microservices absolutely should have their own databases. There are certainly some who would disagree, but a shared database is generally considered an anti pattern.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth but how to link betweents tables for above example

Comment: You should design your databases and microservices around the domain not the data. In this case it sounds like Identity and Competence are closely related and should be accessible from the same microservice - and probably in the same database.

Comment: The short answer is that you don't. @train was correct, microservices should be centered around business functions or context boundaries, not entity relationships. Relationships will exist between services, but the relationships are loosely coupled, not the tight coupling of a database foreign key.

Comment: I think you should step away from DDD, and all those fancy systems and architectural patterns, and just focus on your core business logic first. You will know when you need microseverices, and you will  know when you have sufficient knowledge to implement them without a refactoring nightmare